# Passing <T> from a string parameter to use AddSingleton

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

Why can't I do this?

```
     services.AddSingleton<Type.GetType("ShoppingCartCache",true)>();
```

OR is there a better way of passing  from a string

Comment: Because `Type.GetType` is resolved at runtime but generic parameters must be resolved at compile time.

Comment: so I will have to use dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

The method also has an overload to pass a type as parameter. So you can do:

```cs
services.AddSingleton(typeof(ShoppingCartCache));
```

Same also works with your example (although more prone to runtime errors):

```cs
services.AddSingleton(Type.GetType("ShoppingCartCache",true));
```

The reason it doesn't work is because generic types must be static, thus known at compilation.